# how i can connect interaction

Tags: discord, discord.js

Hi how i can coonect interaction.member.roles.add(role) to another interaction, not who press the button. i need that if you press on a button, bot give role to member who send application

```
  client.on(Events.InteractionCreate, async interaction => {
    
    if (!interaction.isModalSubmit())return;
    const ID = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('IDInput');
    const Rules = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('RulesInput')
    const member = interaction.user;  
    const Rprules = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('RprulesInput')
    console.log(`IC Данные: ${ID}, \n  дискорд: ${member.username} \n знание OOC правил: ${Rules} \n знание IC правил: ${Rprules}`)




    // ембед об новой заявке
    const embedinvite = new EmbedBuilder()
    .setTitle('Новая заявка в Persety Famq!')
    .setDescription(` **новая заявка от игрока в Persety Famq!
    \n IC данные: ${ID}
    \n Дискорд: <@${member.id}>
    \n знание правил сервера: ${Rules}
    \n знание законов Штата: ${Rprules}**`)
    .setColor(`DarkVividPink`)
    .setTimestamp()

    const embedyes = new EmbedBuilder()
    .setTitle('Вы приняли заявку!')
    .setDescription(`<@${member.id}> успешно принят в семью! \n рекрутёр <@>`)
    .setColor('DarkGreen')
    .setTimestamp()


    let inv = "1124436498561896509"
    client.channels.cache.get(inv).send({
         embeds:[embedinvite],
         components:[accept, cancel]
       })


       

    client.on(Events.InteractionCreate, async interaction => {
    

      const role = interaction.message.guild.roles.cache.get('1125451719569047613')
      if (!interaction.isButton()) return;
      if (interaction.customId === 'accept')
        await interaction.member.roles.add(role);
        await client.channels.cache.get(inv).send({
          embeds:[embedyes]
        })
      console.log(member.username)

    })
```

for example, i need that bot give information about user from const member = interaction.user; and  give this user role in this line await interaction.member.roles.add(role);